# Not able to stream video from my Defender SN500-4CH security system

Tags: networking, security, video, streaming

I have a [Defender SN500-4CH v1.0](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/800745/Defender-Sn500-4ch.html) security system. For some reason I am not able to see the broadcast on it when I connect it to the world.

It would ask me to login, so I put the correct user name and password, and it just doesn’t play the video. Everything else works because I am able to change the settings on the system, but I just don’t get any video feed. I could manually see the video it records when I connect a monitor to the system, just not through the Internet.

It's not a problem with active x because i already installed that. I also have their video player which is supposed to stream the video on there but still no luck. I've tried multiple machines. I tried changing the port from `80` to `8080` and still no stream. I tried the other port the manual recommended too. I should even be able to stream this through my phone. I have set up all proper configurations and the right ports for streaming through the phone. I assigned it its own IP address. This is very frustrating because I just can’t figure why don’t I get video feed but I am able to connect to it remotely and change settings.

Answer (score 1):

According to [page 43 of the official manual](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/800745/Defender-Sn500-4ch.html?page=43#manual) for the Defender SN500-4CH v1.0:

> Every computer that is accessing the DVR will need to be configured to
>   download and run ActiveX controls. This change only needs to be made
>   one time on the computer that is accessing the DVR. This can be done by
>   following either of the two methods below. Method 1 only affects
>   websites that you specifically add to the trusted sites list. To
>   change for all websites, use Method 2.

Which tells me that viewing video on your computer is not as simple as just pointing a web browser to the IP address and calling it a day. You need to have ActiveX controls installed and configured. Also you state this:

> I tried changing the port from `80` to `8080` and still no stream. I tried
>   the other port the manual recommended too. I should even be able to
>   stream this through my phone.

Looking at the manual again it seems like the ability to view the video via mobile varies from device-to-device. Some devices require a Java `.jar` program to be installed, but there are also Apple iOS instructions as well when I look at [page 62 of the manual](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/800745/Defender-Sn500-4ch.html?page=43#manual):

> 1. Open up Safari on the iPhone or iTouch.
> 2. In the address bar type in: `http://IPADDRESS/iphone.html`. Ex. `http://74.11.213.177/iphone.html`. You will be prompted to enter a
>      username and password. By default the username/password is
>      admin/admin.
>
> You can change each single camera you are viewing by selecting the
>   active camera from the drop down Menu below. Channels 1-4 are
>   available.

So my best suggestion for you is to see what you can see when you go to your security system’s IP address with the `/iphone.html` page appended to it like this; using `123.456.789.0` as an example IP address:

```
http://123.456.789.0/iphone.html
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort on helping. I could view it using /iphone.html appended to the address but I cant view the video the normal way without the "/iphone.html". I will check if it's active x but i remember already making sure its installed.

Comment: Ok, so i just ran a virtual windows XP machine and it connects perfectly. All features work perfectly on the Windows XP machine. Just doesn't work on Windows 7. I guess this DVR is outdated. I will look and see if i could possibly upgrade the firmware